# Providing implicit conversion functions as parameters in Scala

Tags: scala

I am learning scala using the book "Scala for impatient" by horstmann.

Author has suggested an exercise to define a function Fraction => Ordered[Fraction] and either supply it in the call or make it available as *implicit* val.

Here is my complete code I have implemented in Scala worksheet.

```
    case class Fraction (n:Int,d:Int) {
        def *(that: Fraction):Fraction = new Fraction(n * that.n , d * that.d)
  }

 def smaller[T](a:T,b:T)(implicit order:T => Ordered[T]) = {
   if(a<b) a else b
 }

 implicit def compareFraction(a:Fraction,b:Fraction) ={
    if(a.n  * b.d > a.d * b.n)  a else b
  }

 smaller(Fraction(4,5),Fraction(4,6)) (compareFraction)
```

The smaller function is throwing error while calling with 2 Fraction arguments.

The error is

```
   Type mismatch, expected:(Fraction) => Ordered[Fraction], actual:(Fraction,Fraction) => Ordered.
```

I am struck at creating a function which takes single Fraction as arguments and transforming the same into Ordered[Fraction].

Can anybody help me with implementing the same with both ways below.

1. to define a function Fraction => Ordered[Fraction] and either supply it in the call
2. make it available as *implicit* val.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is something like this:

```
case class Fraction (n:Int,d:Int) {
  def *(that: Fraction):Fraction = new Fraction(n * that.n , d * that.d)
}

def smaller[T](a:T,b:T)(implicit order:T => Ordered[T]) = {
  if(a<b) a else b
}

implicit def fractionToOrdered(fraction: Fraction):Ordered[Fraction] = new Ordered[Fraction] {
  override def compare(that: Fraction): Int = ???
}

smaller[Fraction](Fraction(4,5),Fraction(4,6))
```

Comment: could you please provide implementation for compare method also.